# A more pythonic way to build a class based on a string (how not to use eval)

Tags: python, sqlobject

OK.

So I've got a database where I want to store references to other Python objects (right now I'm using to store inventory information for person stores of beer recipe ingredients).

Since there are about 15-20 different categories of ingredients (all represented by individual SQLObjects) I don't want to do a bunch of RelatedJoin columns since, well, I'm lazy, and it seems like it's not the "best" or "pythonic" solution as it is.

So right now I'm doing this:

```
class Inventory(SQLObject):
    inventory_item_id = IntCol(default=0)
    amount = DecimalCol(size=6, precision=2, default=0)
    amount_units = IntCol(default=Measure.GM)
    purchased_on = DateCol(default=datetime.now())
    purchased_from = UnicodeCol(default=None, length=256)
    price = CurrencyCol(default=0)
    notes = UnicodeCol(default=None)
    inventory_type = UnicodeCol(default=None)

    def _get_name(self):
        return eval(self.inventory_type).get(self.inventory_item_id).name

    def _set_inventory_item_id(self, value):
        self.inventory_type = value.__class__.__name__
        self._SO_set_inventory_item_id(value.id)
```

Please note the ICKY `eval()` in the _get_name() method.

How would I go about calling the SQLObject class referenced by the string I'm getting from `__class__.__name__` without using `eval()`?  Or is this an appropriate place to utilize `eval()`?  (I'm sort of of the mindset where it's never appropriate to use `eval()` -- however since the system never uses any end user input in the `eval()` it seems "safe".)

Comment: couldn't this usage of eval be replaced with `globals()[self.inventory_type]`?

Comment: eval(self.inventory_type) is an imported class object (a subclass of the SQLObject class), not a variable.  doesn't globals() only show declared variables?  And SQLObject.get is not a @classmethod

Comment: if you import a module its name or the names imported appears in the return value of `globals()`. `>>> import os` / `>>> 'os' in globals()` / `True`

Comment: oh crap.  You're right.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of a global by name; Use:

```
globals()[self.inventory_type]
```